# Difference between external event mode versus external interrupt mode for stm32

Tags: stm32, gpio, stm32f0, stm32cubemx, gpio-external-interrupt

I am configuring GPIOs for stm32f0 MCU using CubeMX. I encountered this "GPIO mode" setting. It seems that GPIO mode can be triggered by "External event mode" or "External interrupt mode". See image below. What is the difference between "External event mode" and "External interrupt mode"? Under what situation should one use "External event mode" versus "External interrupt mode"?

[image]

Comment: This ought to be covered in STs technical reference documentation for the part. Its related to how you can detect activity on the pins. Event might relate to using the GPIO to wake from a sleep state, but yoiu need to check.

Comment: I tried reading the reference document. I probably missed it out because it is 771 pages. I will try again.

Comment: This has already been addressed at [Stm32 Event and interrupts](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/114583/stm32-event-and-interrupts) any additional followup should go there to keep the topic in one place.